# Finding a function such that $(n-2)/2 + f(n-1) \leq f(n)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, functional-inequalities

By bounding a certain quantity defined on real numbers by $f(n)$ I derived the following inequality arising from an inductive argument.

$ (n-2)/2 + f(n-1) \leq f(n).$

A solution to the above inequality is obtained by taking $f(n) = n^2.$ Since I want the best possible upper bound for the quantity in question I am wondering

Is there a function $f:\mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{N}$ such that there is a fixed $N$ such that for all $n > N$  we have $$(n-2)/2 + f(n-1) \leq f(n)$$ and $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^2} = 0?$$

It feels that for some fixed $\epsilon > 0$ the function $f(n) = n^{1+\epsilon}$ won't work so I am wondering if there is any other clever way to construct such an $f$ or perhaps whether it is not possible to do so at all?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean for large enough $N$, for every $n\gt N$ the inequality holds?

Comment: Can you find a lower bound of $$f(n) - f(m) = \sum_{k=m+1}^{n} (f(k) - f(k-1)) $$ for $n > m$ using the inequality? Then what can you say about $f(n)/n^2$?

Comment: Note that for all arithmetic sequences, summing over successive terms produces a quadratic sequence.

Comment: @abiessu Yes that's what I mean. I'll correct the question. Though if I understand your last comment it is fact not possible to obtain such f?

Comment: That is correct, as the answer you have shows.

Answer (score 6):

Assume that $f(n)\geq f(n-1)+\frac{n-2}{2}$ holds for $n\geq N$
Then for large $n$, applying the inequality:
$$f(n)\geq f(n-1)+\frac{n-2}{2}\geq f(n-2)+\frac{n-3}{2}+\frac{n-2}{2}\geq \ldots \geq f(N)+\sum_{j=N+1}^{n}\frac{j-2}{2}=$$
$$
=f(N)+\frac{n^2}{4}-\frac{3 n}{4}-\frac{N^2}{4}+\frac{3 N}{4}
$$
Which is of order $n^2$