# Finding a function satisfying a certain inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, functional-inequalities

This is a continuation of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1408121/finding-a-function-such-that-n-2-2-fn-1-leq-fn) post where I tried to find a function $f(n)$ that would satisfy the induction step of an inductive argument and it was shown that such function does not exist.

Trying to fix the problem I've come up with a stronger inductive argument that now requires finding a more elaborate function.

More precisely I would like to find a function $f(n,k)$ such that the following relation would hold for any $0 \leq p \leq (n-2-l)/2$ and $l \leq k$, $l \leq (n-2)$

$$p + f(n-1, k-l+p) \leq f(n,k).$$

$k \geq 0$ can be bounded to anything as long as the induction step still works out.

> Is there a function $f(n,k)$ that satisfies the above inequality such that $$f(n,0) \leq \frac{n^2-6n+6}{6}.$$

Notice that if we take $f(n,k) = n^2-k$, then this gives a solution, but I need the function $f(n,0)$ to be smaller.

Comment: Are the admissible values of $n$, $k$ and $f(n,k)$ non-negative and/or integer?

Comment: @AlexRavsky The admissible values are indeed non-negative. I've also changed the question giving a relaxed condition on $f(n,0).$

Comment: Please edit your question. Some of it is unreadable.

Comment: @StevenGregory Edited the latex part. Is there still anything that is unreadable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a program, which results suggest that the minimal function $\{f(n.0)\}$ satisfying the initial inequality,is 
[$$\{0,0,0,1,2,4,6,9,12,16,20,25,30,36,42,49,56,64,72,81,90,100,110,\dots\}$$](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C4%2C6%2C9%2C12%2C16%2C20%2C25%2C30%2C36%2C42%2C49%2C56%2C64%2C72%2C81%2C90%2C100%2C110%2C121&sort=&language=english&go=Search) that is
$$f(n,0)=\left\lfloor\frac{(n-1)^2}4\right\rfloor.$$

```
program p1413656;
const
 NN=150;
var
  f:array[0..NN,0..NN] of Integer;
  n,k,p,l,lmax,pmax:Integer;
  OFi:Text;
begin
assign(OFi,'1413656.txt');
rewrite(OFi);
for k:=0 to NN do f[0,k]:=0;
for n:=1 to NN do begin for k:=0 to NN do begin
f[n,k]:=0;
if k<=(n-2) then lmax:=k else lmax:=n-2;
 for l:=0 to lmax do begin 
 {I assumed $l\ge 0$, in the opposite case $f(1,0)$ may be infinite}
  pmax:=NN-k+l;
  if pmax>((n-2-l) div 2) then pmax:=((n-2-l) div 2);
  for p:=0 to pmax do if f[n,k]<p+f[n-1,k-l+p] then f[n,k]:=p+f[n-1,k-l+p];
 end;
write(OFi,f[n,k],' ');
end; writeln (OFi) end;
end.
```

Comment: Nice. Now that should already indicate that such function is not to be found right?

Comment: @Jernej Yes, I think that there is no need to work for an upper bound $\sim n^2/4$ when you already have a better upper bound $\sim n^2/6$.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the following.

Provided $n\ge 2$ put $k=l=\left\lfloor\frac{n-2}3\right\rfloor$ and 
$p=\left\lfloor\frac{n-3}3\right\rfloor$. Then

$$\left\lfloor\frac{n-3}3\right\rfloor+f\left(n-1,\left\lfloor\frac{n-3}3\right\rfloor\right)\le f\left(n, \left\lfloor\frac{n-2}3\right\rfloor\right),$$

which should give a lower bound $f\left(n, \left\lfloor\frac{n-2}3\right\rfloor)\right)\ge\frac {n^2}{6}-O(n)$.
Now put $k=l=0$ and $p=\left\lfloor\frac{n-3}3\right\rfloor$.

Then $$f(n,0)\ge p+f(n-1,p)\ge\frac {n^2}{6}-O(n).$$

More precisely. The proposed lower bound is not far from your upper bound $f(n,0) \leq \frac{n^2-6n+6}{6}$. Indeed, for $n\ge 7$ we have

$$f(n,0)\ge \left\lfloor\frac{n-3}3\right\rfloor+f\left(n-1, \left\lfloor\frac{n-3}3\right\rfloor\right)\ge$$ $$\left\lfloor\frac{n-3}3\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{n-4}3\right\rfloor+f\left(n-2, \left\lfloor\frac{n-4}3\right\rfloor\right)\ge$$
$$\left\lfloor\frac{n-3}3\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{n-4}3\right\rfloor+\dots+\left\lfloor\frac{4}3\right\rfloor+f(2,0)\ge$$

$$-\frac{1}3+\sum_{k=4}^{n-3}\frac{k-1}3\ge \frac{n^2-7n+4}6.$$

Comment: Hm! What exactly is the function $f(n,k)$ here? Also the inequality should hold for all $p,k,l$ in the stated interval.

Comment: @Jernej There is no exact function $f(n,k)$ here, there is an asymptotic lower bound for all such functions $f(n,k)$, which follows from the initial inequality, which is supposed to hold for $p,k,l$ in the stated interval.

Comment: I see. Does the lower bound actualy imply that there is no such function - don't we need to figure out what the $O(n)$ term is ?

Comment: @Jernej See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the expanded answer. What is this telling us about the existence of $f?$ If I understand this bound does not imply that $f$ does not exist? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Jernej My answer tells nothing about the existence of $f$.